# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{0}^{1/2-1/n}\sum_{k=1}^nx^{2k+1}\text{arctan}(nx)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, power-series

I've been studying for my upcoming real analysis qual and this was on an older one before the time for the exam was shortened. I've tried substituting the power series for arctan but then I'm not sure what to do with the double sum. I tried estimating the integrals since arctan is bounded by $\pi/2$ to see if I could just integrate over the sum and take the limit to find a bound, and I got a convergent sum, i.e.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{(\frac{n-2}{2n})^{2k+2}}{2k+2}  $$
Which numerically $\approx$0.018841$\dots$ So I'm confident the limit approaches a finite value.

I also tried distributing the integral over the finite sum and then using integration by parts:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\bigg(\big(\dfrac{x^{2k+2}\text{ arctan}(nx)}{2k+2}\bigg|_{x=0}^{x=\frac{n-2}{2n}}\big)-\dfrac{n}{2k+2}\int_{0}^{1/2-1/n}\dfrac{x^{2k+2}}{n^2x^2+1}dx\bigg)$$
But this doesn't seem like I'm going to get anywhere productive following this route. I would appreciate any hints as to how to approach this, this limit has kept me up for many a night!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the $\arctan(nx)$ plays no role in the summation, it is a simple geometric series from then on

$$\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}} x^3\arctan(nx)\frac{1-x^{2n}}{1-x^2}\:dx$$

Then by dominated convergence the integral converges to

$$\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{x^3}{1-x^2}\:dx = \frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{1-x^2}-1\right)\:d(x^2)$$

$$ = \frac{\pi}{4}\Biggr[-\log(1-x^2)-x^2\Biggr]_0^{\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{\pi}{4}\left(\log\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)-\frac{1}{4}\right)$$

Comment: Sorry for not accepting your solution right away, for a while I didn't agree cause I thought your value was negative but I was using log base 10 like an idiot to check *facepalm*, thank you!

Comment: @JnPS you're very welcome! I recently ran into the problem of using $\log_{10}$ to check an integral solution I had. Nearly gave me a heart attack after the integral solution of a complicated looking thing came out looking too good to be true, so I get it.